# how to auto log out if user is inactive for some specific duration using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, logout

If user is inactive for some specific duration, then it should autometically log out. So how I can do this using codeigniter? 
OR 
how to check whether user is active or not after login on that site?

Comment: Question shows no research effort.  Please show your work.

Comment: Read CI documentation its for reading.. :) http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html $this->session->sess_destroy();

Comment: be careful not to implement in the data entry page where the user might need some time to input the data over some time e.g. 30 minutes (in my case)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
// Add the following into your HEAD section
var timer = 0;
function set_interval() {
  // the interval 'timer' is set as soon as the page loads
  timer = setInterval("auto_logout()", 10000);
  // the figure '10000' above indicates how many milliseconds the timer be set to.
  // Eg: to set it to 5 mins, calculate 5min = 5x60 = 300 sec = 300,000 millisec.
  // So set it to 300000
}

function reset_interval() {
  //resets the timer. The timer is reset on each of the below events:
  // 1. mousemove   2. mouseclick   3. key press 4. scroliing
  //first step: clear the existing timer

  if (timer != 0) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = 0;
    // second step: implement the timer again
    timer = setInterval("auto_logout()", 10000);
    // completed the reset of the timer
  }
}

function auto_logout() {
  // this function will redirect the user to the logout script
  window.location = "your_logout_script.php";
}

// Add the following attributes into your BODY tag
onload="set_interval()"
onmousemove="reset_interval()"
onclick="reset_interval()"
onkeypress="reset_interval()"
onscroll="reset_interval()"
```

Comment: It has been copied from:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572938/force-logout-users-if-users-are-inactive-for-a-certain-period-of-time That is not the we to post answers!

Answer (score 1):

You can save the time that your user logged-in in a `session` or a `cookie`

Example: `$this->session->set_userdata('time', time());`
and use a javascriptjQuery function (Exp. `$.getJSON('time.php', function (data) {alert(data.serverTime);});`) or anything else to check the current time. Then, log your user out when needed.

However, next time, please place code or something else that shows your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $minutes=3;//Set logout time in minutes    
    if (!isset($_SESSION['time'])) {
        $_SESSION['time'] = time();
    } else if (time() – $_SESSION['time'] > $minutes*60) {
        session_destroy();
        header(‘location:login.php’);//redirect user to a login page or any page to which we want to redirect.
    }
?>
```

... which was originally taken from <s>skillrow.com/log-out-user-if-user-is-inactive-for-certain-time-php/</s> (now 404).

Comment: @Matt: as per your code user will be logged out after x minutes, 3 minutes in this case, even if user is active. Here is my modified solution:                          $minutes = 3;
if(isset($_SESSION['time']) && (time()-$_SESSION['time'] > $minutes*60)){
    header('location:'. 'logout_url.php');
    die();
}
// set time if empty and user is logged in
if($userLoggedIn){
    $_SESSION['time'] = time();
}

Comment: @shairya: it is not my code, it's kamal's. I only [edited his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23903794/revisions)