# How to insert timeout into login.php?

Tags: php, android

This is my LOGIN.php:

```
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    // receiving the post params
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // get the user by email and password
    $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);

    if ($user != false) {
        // use is found

        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
        $response["user"]["cognome"] = $user["cognome"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["email2"] = $user["email2"];
        $response["user"]["numero_appartamento"] = $user["numero_appartamento"];
        $response["user"]["nome_edificio"] = $user["nome_edificio"];
        $response["user"]["zona_metropolitana"] = $user["zona_metropolitana"];
        $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
        $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
        header('Content-type: application/json');

        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user is not found with the credentials
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Login credentials are wrong. Please try again!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required post params is missing
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters email or password is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

How can i insert a `timeout` of 30 minutes?

THANKS IN ADVANCE EVERYBODY!

Comment: `timeout` to do what?

Comment: @DanielDudas: OP probably wants to create a session after a successful login, and is asking how to set a TTL for said session

Comment: after 30 minutes session must  expired

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21807025/how-to-destroy-session-automatically-after-5-minutes-of-inactivity-on-website-in

Comment: ZainFarooq how can i integrate it into my login.php?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)

Comment: @user6612196 - could you please stop editing all those exclamations into your post?

Answer (score 0):

If you're relying on [server-side sessions](http://php.net/book.session) to keep the user logged in simply set your session TTL to 30 minutes to ensure that the user only remains logged in for no longer than 30 minutes of inactivity. This can be achieved using the [session.gc_maxlifetime](http://php.net/session.configurationp#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) directive. Like `ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 1800)`, but make sure you set the `session.cookie_lifetime` to a value equal to or higher than the `session.gc_maxlifetime` and also make sure you read the manual carefully about some gotchyas when changing `session.gc_maxlifetime` values for multiple sessions in the same path.

## A few more important notes about your code

I notice you're looking up the user supplied password in your database directly, which indicates that you are storing a **plain-text password**. You really  ***must hash user passwords before storing them in your database*** using something like [`password_hash`](http://php.net/password-hash), for example. This is very important in storing user passwords.