# Automatically log out the user if he is not active for a certain period of time

Tags: php, session

I want a user to be automatically logged out after 30 minutes if he hasn't been active.

I've tried the following code :
Index.php :

```
<?  
if ((time() - $_SESSION['last_activity']) > 1800) // 30* 60 = 1800
{  
   header("Location: logout.php");  
}  
?>
```

login.php:

```
<?  
        $_SESSION['unm'] = $row['u_unm'];
        $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['u_pwd'];
        $_SESSION['status'] = true;
        $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time();  
?>
```

My problem is I don't understand how this code is keeping track of user activity?

The problem I am facing is determining whether the user is active or not. But I want the user only to be logged out if he is not doing anything.

Can anybody tell me how to keep track of that?  Thanks.

Comment: For one `>?` should give you some kind of error

Comment: Opps. Typing mistake.. FIxed that.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124560/how-to-expire-php-session-if-user-is-inactive-for-15-mins

Comment: Just so you know - Sessions live for 1440 seconds (24 minutes) by default. `:)` Just thought I'd put that in. (editable in config) - Also it's possible that in the header each time it's loaded the `$_SESSION['last_activity'] = time()` can be ran to give that data.

Comment: may this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572938/force-logout-users-if-users-are-inactive-for-a-certain-period-of-time) will help you Thank you....

Comment: @Jek  Can you please explain to me how this code keeps tracking the activity? I mean is it not just keeping the session for 30 minutes and then destroy it whether the user did something or not? I've basically created this session($_SESSION['last_activity']) when a user will be successfully logged in. Doesn't that mean the user will always be logged out after 30 minutes?

Comment: I'm saying this would fix your solution to the "how does it get `$_SESSION['last_activity']`, you'd post this before your check. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you only have the index.php. Try to modify your code like this:

```
<?  
if ((time() - $_SESSION['last_activity']) > 1800) // 30* 60 = 1800
{  
   header("Location: logout.php");  
} else {
   $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time();
}
?>
```

This will only update your session, if the user did something under your 30 mins.

Seems like you don't use a library, so you could need to implement this on every site you have.

---

**EDIT**

Create a new file, which could be named as `lifesaver.php` or something like this. In this file, you paste the code from above.

Now you include it on every page you have, like this: `require('lifesaver.php');`

This will include your file and you have the code from above in your site.

Explanation how the code from above works:

> **EDIT:** Basically reload the page in 30 or greater minutes and you'll automatically be taken to `logout.php`. If you reload the page sooner than 30 minutes your time will be updated(meaning another 30 minutes till automatic logout). The code is executed every time a user reloads or goes to a page with this script. – [Antono](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6061856/antono)

Comment: Then you have to implement this to every site you have. You could create a new file with this code and include it to every site you have.

Comment: Suppose I have 3 pages : index.php, Contact.php and About.php.  Shouldn't I need to include this code to each page?  Otherwise how could it set the timer when I will be in Contact page?

Comment: @OptimizedFaisal you could move it into a file and require it for every page. Or you could put that in a class and do `spl_autoload_register()` for that.

Comment: Can you please explain to me how this code keeps tracking the activity?  I mean is it not just keeping the session for 30 minutes and then destroy it  whether the user did something or not?  I've basically created this session($_SESSION['last_activity']) when a user will be successfully logged in. Doesn't that mean the user will always be logged out after 30 minutes?

Comment: @Antono Thank you for your explaination. It is now more clear to me. :)

Comment: **EDIT:** Basically reload the page in 30 or greater minutes and you'll automatically be taken to `logout.php`. If you reload the page sooner than 30 minutes your time will be updated(meaning another 30 minutes till automatic logout). The code is executed every time a user reloads or goes to a page with this script.